# Applying to an object property, the value of a variable, rather than the variable name

Tags: javascript, json

Lets say there's a loop, and through each iteration the variable `temp` iterates upwards from `1` to `10`. So:

```
var arr["age", "address", "email"];
var personel={};
personel.info={};

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    var temp = arr[i];
    personel.info.temp = null;
}
```

(This code could be wrong I've just made it up quickly, but I hope you know what I mean)

I have code somewhat like this myself, and the desired output from me would be:

```
{
    "Personel": {
        "Info": {
            "age": null,
            "address": null,
            "email": null
        }
    }
}
```

**However** The output I've been getting has been more like this:

```
{
    "Personel": {
        "Info": {
            "temp": null
        }
    }
}
```

So to reiterate, how do you make it so that the `personel.info.temp` takes the value of `temp` and not just the word "temp"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties) instead:

```
personel.info[temp] = null;
```

Check out [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) on MDN for more information.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6DBWD/

Comment: Thank you both for the fast response!

Comment: If only I'd added a fiddle as well :p

Answer (score 3):

Like so:

```
 personel.info[temp] = null;
```

See [this MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) for more on the `.` and `[]` operators.